# How to Send Get request with Body using Playwright

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

I'm trying to send a get request with a body using playwright.
I did not find any resource / way how to do it.
I would like to query the elasticsearch using get request with payload.
example:

```
test("Get simki", async ({request})=> {
    const response = await request.get('http://test,test.be/es/ad_matrix_agg_*/_search', {
        headers:{
            'Authorization': 'Basic token',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    }); 
    console.log(await response.json());
    expect(response.status()).toBe(200);
})
```

there is no option to add data in get request like in post request.

will appreciate any assistance on this matter.

trying to use data in get request did not work and got this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add a body like this under `data`

```js
test('Get simki', async ({request}) => {
  const response = await request.get(
    'http://test,test.be/es/ad_matrix_agg_*/_search',
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Basic token',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      data: {
        key1: 'value1',
        key2: 'value2',
        key3: 'value3',
        key4: 'value4',
      },
    }
  )
  console.log(await response.json())
  expect(response.status()).toBe(200)
})
```

Comment: Hi Alapan, i added a screenshot while trying to add data to get request. data cannot be added (maybe) to get request?

Comment: If you see this example https://playwright.dev/docs/test-api-testing#writing-tests, this is the way to pass request body. Not sure why it doesn't work then.

Comment: it works with post but with get there is no option to send body/ payload .. this is why i raised this issue in the first place. i hope that there is a workaround / solution for it in playwright.

Comment: i would suggest opening an issue on their github

Comment: i opened this issue- https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/16930